# How do I create a matrix from a dataframe with 3 columns in Python

Tags: python, matrix

In Python I have created a dataframe that has four columns, related to a list of shares listed on various exchanges around the world. The columns are:

```
Stock ticker, 
Country of listing, 
Industry Sector, 
PE multiple
```

I want to create a matrix, that collates the data so that along the X axis I see the various countries, and along the Y axis I see the various sectors.  Within each cell I'd like to get the median PE multiple of all the companies that are in each combination of country and sector - e.g. banks in USA and Engineering in UK.

Comment: if you do a `df.values` it will give a nice numpy array as you want it to. df here is the name of the pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to explain a little more...for eg: where are the 'companies' are listed?

But from what I understand, you're looking for something like

```
df.groupby(by=['Country of listing','Industry Sector'])['PE multiple'].median().unstack(level=0)
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly first time!  Thankyou so much for your time ansd apologies for not being able to give more information.  I'm just starting out using the BQuant module within Bloomberg and the database query is unlike anything I've seen before!